# wrong expected arguments of @ViewChild and ngAfterViewInit doesn't work

Tags: angular, paginator, viewchild

I am following the [guidance](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnbermjydavk?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.html)
However, the @ViewChild and ngAfterViewInit do not work for me. The error information is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCBsQ.png). It said I miss one argument. And I have tried to add 2 arguments like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFZS4.png), but it still does not work. And the ngAfterViewInit also has some problems.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wO3G.png)

Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: please share your code i stacblitz, we cannot help you without seeing the full code

Comment: my code is almost as same as the [link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnbermjydavk?file=app%2Ftable-overview-example.html) but i use <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> and <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> instead of <mat-head-cell><mat-cell>. i dont know if it will influence the result>

Comment: if its same, it should work like a charm. create your own stackblitz and please share the link. we will help

Answer (score 1):

**Note: If you use Angular 8**

In angular 8 @ViewChild is require two argument. before 8 version @ViewChild require only one argument. Please see below code.

**Example: @ViewChild**

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

you must implements **AfterViewInit** before use **ngAfterViewInit**

**Example: ngAfterViewInit**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
})
export class ListComponent implements AfterViewInit { // <-- implements here

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

    constructor(){}

    ngAfterViewInit() {

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer !! The @ViewChild works for me now after I declare it according your method. However, the ngAfterViewInit() still has problem. If add this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator ; this.dataSource.sort = this.sort; in constructor(){}, it works well. But if I put them in ngAfterViewInit(), it doesn't work! do you know why? Many thanks!